# how to remove a title from one exact page?

Tags: header-footer

[image]Today I'm asking how can I remove a subsection title, keeping the page number, from an exact page? I've rotated the page and put an image and you can see that it appears '4.4 ALB' over the page.
I've tried 
\pagestyle{plain}\setcounter{25} (25 it's the page), but it didn't work. Actually it deleted from page 24 to 27 (cause it's the end of the chapter).
I've tried \thispagestyle but neither this worked.
So I hope someone can help me.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7,keepaspectratio]{plot/ctree.png}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
    \pagestyle{plain}\setcounter{25}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3):

with use `landscape` environment (because it is not float environment and therefore is simple add `\thispagestyle{empty}`) instead `sidewaysfigure` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}   % <--- added
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{my figure}
    \label{fig:landscape}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernard can explain me the \lipsum function? I've tried what you wrote putting \lipsum[25-26] (the pages) but it didn't work.

Comment: `\lipsum[m-n]` gives access to  §§ m to n to the *Lorem ipsum* dummy text (it is a dummy text used by typographers for testing purposes, written i a sort of fake Latin). Maybe you didn't install it?

Comment: @Bernard I saw it writes in latin, but it makes my figures and tables disappear! I don't understand how it should work.. I need only page 25, how can I set it?

Comment: It's  not ‘page’, but ‘paragraph’. Simply use `\lipsum[25]`.

Comment: @SMoini, my document example (called minimal working example: mwe)  generate only three page which demonstrate the principle, how it works. it will work also at page 25 of your document. of course, in your document you should remove `\lipsum` which serve me only to demonstrate my solution.